# Using dash_cytoscape line-gradient-stop-colors

Tags: python, css, plotly-dash, cytoscape.js

I am attempting to create gradients within the edges of a graph in `dash_cytoscape` using `line-gradient-stop-colors` (from [the js.cytoscape documentation](https://js.cytoscape.org/#style/gradient)). I am doing this with a stylesheet that describes a gradient layout for all of the edges in my graph.  Example code is below, however it creates a graph with just grey edges.

```
import dash
import dash_cytoscape as cyto
from dash import html

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

style_1 = [
    {
        'selector': 'node',
        'style': {
            'label': 'data(id)',
            'background-color': 'blue',
        }
    },
    {
        'selector': 'edge',
        'style': {
            'line-gradient-stop-colors': 'cyan magenta yellow', # these are the lines that I have issue with
            'line-gradient-stop-positions': '25 50 75',
    }
    }
]

app.layout = html.Div([
    cyto.Cytoscape(
        id='cytoscape-elements-boolean',
        layout={'name': 'preset'},
        style={'width': '100%', 'height': '800px'},
        stylesheet=style_1,
        elements=[
            {
                'data': {'id': 'one'},
                'position': {'x': 75, 'y': 75},
            },
            {
                'data': {'id': 'two'},
                'position': {'x': 75, 'y': 200},
            },
            {
                'data': {'id': 'three'},
                'position': {'x': 200, 'y': 75},
            },
            {
                'data': {'id': 'four'},
                'position': {'x': 200, 'y': 200}
            },
            {'data': {'source': 'one', 'target': 'two'}},
            {'data': {'source': 'two', 'target': 'three'}},
            {'data': {'source': 'three', 'target': 'four'}},
            {'data': {'source': 'two', 'target': 'four'}},
        ]
    )
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

I believe the issue is how I have the line-gradient-stop-colors string set up but I've tried multiple options and none of them have worked.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It says "0% 50% 100%"